# Applying in Germany - how far back should the documentary evidence go?

Tags: faculty-application, germany

Let's assume that some of your applications go for W2 professorship positions at the German universities of applied sciences. One of such potential employers asks the candidates to supply

> Lebenslauf, belegt durch Zeugniskopien und Nachweise der beruflichen Tätigkeit [...]

(CV, supported through credential copies and evidence of occupation [...])

Let's assume you have been on *a lot* of academic short-term contracts and stipends since your undergraduate studies. Is it really expected that you supply *all* the documents (over 15 in your case)? Or are documents for the recent *n* years sufficient? (Yes, you asked the person in charge, and that person did not respond. Moreover, you know noone from the faculty...)

On the one hand, you may be afraid that in case of a huge number of incoming applications for the position there could be a pre-selection phase, in which some assistants would reduce the number of applications to look at by simply filtering out the applications which are not 100% conforming. Or that some committee members insist strictly on the rules.

On the other hand, properly preparing all the documents would take you 1 full working day. Reason: the documents are not in easy-to-handle formats (PNG, multi-page TIFF with different-size pages, white paper, etc.), the salary needs to be blackened, all kinds of printer issues have to be dealt with, etc. One day is a lot for you. It is unknown whether any of the next 100 potential employers would need these documents (the previous 60 did not need them), so the work you are doing might not be reusable.

Comment: What is the issue with supplying all these documents? Nowadays, that usually is just some additional pages in a PDF.

Comment: @Roland It's in other formats than PDF, including pure paper. Not only some scanning of old junk is necessary but also blackening the salary (partially to meet the obligations of the former employers and partially to have a better basis for negotiations). Overall, simply preparing the documentary evidence would be 1 full working day or more for you.

Comment: If you want to work in Germany you'll have to do that work sooner or later. Why not do it now?

Comment: @Roland Even if I work in Germany later, it can happen that I'd never ever change the employer...

Comment: It certainly doesn't take one day to scan some documents and save them as PDF. You should do that anyways. Blackening can be done easily in PDF

Comment: @DSVA Each single action (say, purely scanning) takes minimal time. The scanner is done within 10-30 seconds per page. But scanning properly (failures do occur from time to time), *organizing* the scanned documents into directories and files, naming them properly such that you'd be able to find them later, blackening the salary (without adobe acrobat in linux), and printing (dealing with the tranditional issues while printing) -  all that, combined, does take a lot of my time. How did you do it?

Comment: Well, I just batch scanned them, renamed them and put them in a backed up folder. Overall less than a minute of work per 1-page dokument if you are doing several. I'm doing this for every new document too, takes maybe 3 minutes overall. I usually don't have problems while printing. Blackening does take more effort but I never needed to do that until now. Overall I think you are overthinking this a lot. Even if it's two or 3 hours of work (most of it is a one-time thing) that's far away from a day of work.

Comment: @DSVA Oh. I see. Batch-scan is possible if you both (1) have a document as separate sheets (and are not afraid to detach the sheets if it's not the case) and (2) have access to a machine that does batch-scanning. As for me, I'm afraid to unstaple the original document (since I might need to show it in its original form to someone else later), and I don't have access to a batch-scanner. As for blackening, are you not afraid to show your old salaries to the new employers? Or are they always sufficently high?

Comment: Well, there's proof that you worked in a company without having the salaries on it. What are you using? Your contracts? That's what employment reference letters or certificates of employment are for.

Answer (score 6):

If you did not get an answer from the person in charge, I see two possibilities:

1. Go all in and send all documents. You have them all ready anyway (you have them, right?) and if they request it, they can have it. If you go for this option, make sure that your CV is well organized and that the whole application document is perfectly ordered as well.
2. Just attach the most recent ones and add something like "Complete documents can be given if needed". This may save you some time and maybe the committee will not need the documents anyway.

From my experience, these rules often sound more strict than in reality and in reality the committee often does not know the exact rules anyway. But there is always the possibility that some committee member insists on following all rules to the single letter.

Another thing: Often there are two people to ask questions about the ad: The dean and the head of the committee. You may also ask other faculty members at the institution if you happen to know somebody there.

Another remark: As a head of a search committee it is pretty normal to receive phone calls close to the application deadline, so it a question is urgent, rather call than write an email.

Comment: Thank you. I'm afraid that there could be a preselection phase, in which some assistants would reduce the number of applications to look at by simply filtering out the applications which are not 100% conforming.

Comment: I haven't heard of such a preselection process by assistants happening for such a position.

Answer (score 1):

I would not bother to include any contracts that pertained to your time during your undergraduate days, either at the bachelor's or master's phases, since it essentially represents part-time work during your studies. Nor do you need to show a work contract for your doctoral phase—your diplomas and transcripts represent the needed documentation for those phases.

You do need to account for your time *after* your doctoral studies are complete, and for any significant period of time that elapsed between your undergraduate and graduate studies, if any. (If it's a summer, you don't need to submit anything; if it's a year or more, you should have *some* sort of accounting for that period. If you were working in Germany, you can request *Zeugnisse* from employers to confirm your applications, without having to disclose your salary and other confidential information.